# Currency translation

Tags: python, conditional-statements, calculation

[Snapshot of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en8xq.png)
I have a big dataframe consisting of U.S. Dollar statements and Canadian Dollar statements over a period of 20 years. I need to translate the Canadian statements to U.S.$ by dividing them with the average currency rates of that specific year.

```
df = pd.Dataframe([[1998,'CAD',123,1234],[1999,'CAD',345,1233],[1999,'USD',454,1232],[1999,'USD',2333,3456]], columns=['year','currency','net_profit','revenue'])

year currency net_profit revenue
1998 CAD      123        1234
1999 CAD      345        1233
1999 USD      454        1232
1999 USD      2333       3456
```

I can find the CAD companies in 1998 with this code.

```
 filter_1998 = firm[(firm['currency']== 'CAD') & (firm.Year ==1998)]
```

After that, I need to translate these rows with the average currency rate of 1998, 1USD /1,4811 CAD. To convert these rows of Canadian statements, I wanted to put in a condition.

```
if firm[(firm['currency'] == CAD)&(firm['year']==1998:
pd.divide(x) / 1,4811
Translated CAD values into USD.
```

The first row will be divided by the exchange rate. The desired result would look like this:

```
    year currency net_profit revenue
    1998 CAD      83.05      833.16
    1999 CAD      345        1233
    1999 USD      454        1232
    1999 USD      2333       3456
```

So how can I calculate solely with the rows that I have selected with the condition and still replace the CAD values with the USD values?

Comment: Please provide a minimal dataframe, which we can copy paste and execute

Comment: You say `...&(firm['year']==1998` so why are you surprised it's only converting the first row?

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, using the average rate is not a translation.

Comment: @PrinceFrancis I added a minimal dataframe

Comment: @po.pe Sorry for the misunderstanding. That is exactly what I want! However, since I have a dataset of thousands of observations, I want to calculate all values of 1998 and CAD with the exchange rate.

Comment: @Alexander I am aware it's not the proper way to translate a balance sheet. However, I am allowed to simplify the translation process by using the average rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `merge` and `np.where` as follows.
I assume you have average rate of each year in another dataframe.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1998,'CAD',123,1234],[1999,'CAD',345,1233],[1999,'USD',454,1232],[1999,'USD',2333,3456]], columns=['year','currency','net_profit','revenue'])
df_rate = pd.DataFrame([[1998, 1.4811], [1999, 1.3798]],columns=['year','rate'])
df = df.merge(df_rate, how='left', on='year')
df['revenue'] = np.where(df['currency'] == 'CAD',df['revenue']/df['rate'],df['revenue'])
df
```

The output is as follows

```
    year    currency    net_profit  revenue     rate
0   1998    CAD     123     833.164540  1.4811
1   1999    CAD     345     893.607769  1.3798
2   1999    USD     454     1232.000000     1.3798
3   1999    USD     2333    3456.000000     1.3798
```